# Отслеживание динамического изменения высоты блока

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть верстка. Sticky header, размер которого изменяется в зависимости от скролла страницы, а сам хедер становится `position:fixed` (сделано путем добавления css-класса в момент прокрутки). По нажатию на любой из пунктов меню происходит скролл к нужной секции. 
Столкнулся с проблемой потребности смещения якорей из-за фиксированного header

Написал следующий код.

```
$page = $('html, body');
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
    $page.animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - $('.header').height()
    }, 700);
    return false;
});
```

Идеально работает с фиксированным header`ом. Но если вернуться к стандартному (высота которого отличается от sticky) и нажать на пункт меню, всё равно происходит смещение (скроллит не туда куда нужно).
Видимо проблема в том что `$('.header').height()` (который считывает высоту блока) срабатывает только один раз.

Как можно динамически отслеживать изменение высоты header`a, и использовать это значение при просчете того, на сколько нужно сместить скролл? Желательно средствами языка, без библиотек.

Comment: `Желательно средствами языка, без библиотеk`, а у самого код на jquery написан)

Comment: Исходя из вопроса, особо не вникая в код, вижу 2 решения 1) Определять высоту хедера непосредственно перед скролом. У Вас не работает, т.к., возможно, Jquery кеширует элемент. Но я не в курсе, т.к. не работаю с Jquery 2) Использовать MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Имел ввиду библиотек для ресайза) Спасибо, попробую.